# An exception Error is here. How should i deal with it in doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

[Doubly Linked List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXuDn.png)

Here I wrote A deletion Function for deletion of a node of doubly linked list. But its showing this exception . I don't know how to deal with any exception.

Comment: A loop `while (temp != NULL &&.....)` can end with `temp` being `NULL`. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not as a picture. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: i want to delete a node to which i have named it `temp` temporary . `count` is initialised with one as `pos` traversal and it traverse till `(temp!=NULL && count!=pos)`

Comment: Before the line that the code crashes on which dereferences temp, you should check if temp is a null pointer and exit the function. I assume a NULL temp means whatever node you were looking for was not in the list.